# Could not find artifact com.gemstone:gemfire-modules:jar:7.0.1 in JBoss repository

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss

I am getting the following error while building a maven project.

The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.gemstone:gemfire-modules:jar:7.0.1, com.gemstone:gemfire-modules-hibernate:jar:7.0.1.

Could not find artifact com.gemstone:gemfire-modules:jar:7.0.1 in JBoss repository (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]

I also tried http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss repository.
Can anyone help me with it ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not available in jboss repository you need to add [`gemstone`](http://dist.gemstone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/release/) repository, add following to your `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gemstone</id>
        <url>http://dist.gemstone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/release/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Now it shows access denied.                                            Could not transfer artifact com.gemstone:gemfire-modules:pom:7.0.1 from/to jboss.repository.releases.public (http://dist.gemstone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/release/): Access denied to: http://dist.gemstone.com.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/release/com/gemstone/gemfire-modules/7.0.1/gemfire-modules-7.0.1.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Please add following line of code end of pom.xml

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>gemfire-repository</id>
      <name>Gemfire Repository</name>
      <url>http://dist.gemstone.com/maven/release</url>
     </repository>
</repositories>
```